# How to go next page ++ in UIPageviewController when i click UIButton in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Now I am creating app tour for my app by using `uipageviewcontroller`, its working fine when I am swipe the pages in view controller but what I need was the page will move when I click the button
below is my button click action here i can able to put only custom page index but I need to give the current page of the index

```
- (IBAction)donebtnaction:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"current page: %@",indexpathpage);

    PageContent *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.PageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

and i am also tried to save the index when swipe after and swipe before,

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    NSUInteger index = ((PageContent*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound){
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    [self.pagecontrol setCurrentPage:index];
    if (index == [self.arrPageTitles count])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Please give me solution for this .

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating the page by pop and push actions . That will help to which action u are performing and which indexPath its heading .

For example for push which is inserting from stack

```
 xController *xVC = [[xController alloc]init];
xVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:xVC animated:YES];}
```

for example to pop which means taking it out from the stack

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: chintz i don't need to move the page from one view controller to another view controller i am using pageviewcontroller to move